# Ordinary least squares fitting in 3d

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

This is probably fairly obvious, but I'm seeking clarification on something I came across regarding ordinary least squares fitting in 3d.

If by minimizing the sum $|ax_i+by_i+c-z_i|^2$ we can construct the plane $f(x,y)=ax+by+c$ so that the sum of squared distances of our points from this plane is the smallest, what do we get by conversely looking for planes $g(x,z)$ and $h(y,z)$?

Just by guessing, I'd think they should represent the same plane, but if I make up some points and try to fit them (using $A^\dagger Ax=A^\dagger b$), it's clear that they don't. In cases when the points are almost coplanar curiously I get planes that are very similar to each other, but not identical.

So I hope I'm making myself sufficiently understood, the question is if the plane $f(x,y)$ is the least squares fit, how to interpret planes $g(x,z)$ and $h(y,z)$? What is being minimized? Thanks for any help.

Comment: It may be worth simplifying to the 2D case. If you have data which is perfectly linearly correlated, then fitting $y$ as a function of $x$ will give the same result as $x$ as a function of $y$. If the correlation isn't perfect, though, then these fits will not be identical. Moreover, the angle between these fits is one way to define the correlation coefficient!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plane $f(x,y)=ax+by+c$ is a model that is a plane that must meet the $z$-axis.  The squared distance between this plane and the data points given by
$$  |f(x_i,y_i) - z_i|^2  $$
measures the distance between the plane and the $i^\text{th}$ point in the $z$-direction.

$$  |g(x_i,z_i) - y_i|^2  $$
measures the distance between the plane and the $i^\text{th}$ point in the $y$-direction.

$$  |h(y_i,z_i) - x_i|^2  $$
measures the distance between the plane and the $i^\text{th}$ point in the $x$-direction.

As you have discovered, varying the direction along which the "error" between the data and the model is measured changes the total "error", and so alters the model fit.

Comment: So in other words I misunderstood the whole method, because it is not the orthogonal distance from the points to the plane that is being minimized (which I assumed), but rather the distance in a given direction, is that correct?

Comment: Yes.  The error is based on the "vertical" distance, not the orthogonal distance.  If the deviations of the data from the model are the same in two directions, then the absolute errors are multiplied by a constant going from one direction to the other.  See [Deming regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_regression) and also the section "orthogonal regression" there for more about this.